# Android Browser Intent back button

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello  I am lauching the browser from my application using an intent such as:

```
String url = "XXXX";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

but when I press back on the browser i want to go back to the my application, instead of going to the options of the browser. how can i control this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't** as the back button implementation is now under control of **Browser Application**.

Implement a `WebView` in your application and handle **Back Key Pressed** is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

A task (from the activity that started it to the next task activity) defines an atomic group of activities that the user can move to. Tasks can be moved to the foreground and background; all of the activities inside of a particular task always remain in the same order. You can find more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Even doing this you can't handle back button of Browser Application. As may be in there is implementation for Back Key Click.