# How to make sure the back button returns to my app after firing startActivity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an app that interconnects with Google Drive through their Java Rest API to open documents.

I am using the following code to open the document on Google Drive

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(results.get(0)));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

The thing is the user can return to my app with back button if Google Drive was previously closed, but if its already opened the user can't get back to my app with the back button and instead returns to previous activities inside Google Drive.

I tried setting several flags like the following to no avail

```
browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Using those flags don't fix my problem what flags can i use then?

Comment: Try this: Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(results.get(0)));
startActivity(browserIntent); finish();

Comment: @KuldeepKulkarni Using finish(); will close my app and i don't want that! I want the user to return back to my app from Google Drive even if it was previously open.

Comment: See the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367602/android-browser-intent-back-button

Comment: There are those who say `startActivityForResult()` will create an activity that returns to your activity, but it didn't work for me. I just settled for not `finish()`ing the main activity after raising the report intent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are opening another application then you can't control its Activities stack which makes sense.

So if App is already running then its stack might contain activities. Which comes to screen when user press back key.

Functionality which you want can be added, like we can check user came from another Application then kill my App(third party/launched App) on press of back. But what will happen according to the user perspective if he navigated through few options and put his App in background for later work then suddenly everything clear.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but if the request to open the file came from another app (my app) shouldn't the expected behavior to be for the user to return to my app on back press?

Comment: No, for better understanding you can create one example which accept image or a file. So you will find just one instance of Application will open.

Comment: Ok then the user has to make sure Google Drive is closed in order for the app to work has intended by my client, no other way around it?

Comment: No you have to rely on Google Drive and more you can show some alert to user that now you will navigated to blah blah.

Comment: Killing my app wouldn't solve anything because i want the user to return to my app with the back button after i requested Google Drive to open a file.

Comment: Here I mean like third party Apps can implement that logic. Like kill Google Drive if some another App launched it.